# How can I leave Malaysia and return home to India when my employer is holding my passport?

Tags: indian-citizens, passports, legal, malaysia

My friend wants to come back to India as he is not okay with the work situation in Malaysia. However, his passport is with his employer. How can he return to India without a valid passport?

Comment: Let the employer know that [witholding the passport is illegal](https://www.thestar.com.my/news/nation/2014/12/21/withholding-passports-illegal-govt-warns-in-a-bid-to-curb-human-trafficking-the-home-affairs-ministr/)? If that doesn't work, go to the police. Be prepared to be expelled from Malaysia and not be able to return if things go bad. I would recommend talking to a relevant NGO before doing anything for better advice, though.

Comment: Go to the Indian embassy and request a new passport. That will lack the entry stamps, so there would be questions on leaving Malaysia, but India will let him in with that.

Answer (score 4):

Just apply for a new passport. Say it's lost.

Comment: Or say that it's being held ilegally and involve the police, if that's an option.

Comment: I think saying exactly what is going on is far better than making up some story.

Comment: I agree, but the person in question might not be in a comfortable situation. They are clearly being retained against their will, and there might be a chance for things to get violent. If that's the case, pretending to have lost the passport can be an acceptable choice. One can always (at least try to) rectify things when back in safety.

Comment: At least for a lost American passport, that requires explaining the circumstances of loss, under penalty of perjury. I would ask the Indian Embassy for advice on whether the Malaysian police will be helpful. They will have heard this story many times before.